# Which Javascript code editor supports plain text line numbering?

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, line-numbers, plaintext

I need to add a text area that also has line numbering capabilities. I tried `EditArea`, but I couldn't make it work with text files. It would be ideal if it could highlight syntax for existing programming languages, but that would only be a side bonus.

The main thing I'm after is line numbering for whatever I paste in it. Please only list open source ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/), we can configure it to show line numbers.

> Etherpad is a highly customizable Open Source online editor providing
>   collaborative editing in really real-time

Other opensource alternatives [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and [Firepad](https://firepad.io)

> Firepad is feature rich, built on [Google's Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?utm_source=demo&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=firepad), so no need to setup a server